# Is a weak-star compact subset of $L^\infty$ automatically bounded under the $L^\infty$-norm?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to know if a weak-star compact subset of $L^\infty$ automatically bounded under the $L^\infty$-norm. This does not seem to be covered by Arzela-Ascoli, or does it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By the principle of uniform boundedness, a weak-* compact set in the dual of a Banach space is always bounded.